# Find the volume $V_y$ of the figure bounded by the lines $y=x^2,x=3,y=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, solid-of-revolution

Find the volume $V_y$ of the figure bounded by the lines $y=x^2,x=3,y=0$

**I tried:**

> $$V_y=\pi \int_{0}^{3} x^4 dx=\pi \frac {3^5}{5}$$

Is this solution correct?

Comment: Are you referring to a revolution solid around x axis?

Comment: Around $O_y$ ..

Comment: You should precise this point in the OP, are you looking for the volume of the solid of revolution around the y axis?

Comment: Yes you are right..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivation is correct for the volume for the solid of revolution around the $x$ axis by disk method.

Note that, for to the volume for the solid of revolution around the $y$ axis by disk method the set up would be

$$\pi \int_{0}^{9} (9-y)\, dy$$

Comment: How did you find this formula?

Comment: Opsss there was a typo. To see that make a sketch; for each fixed value of y the elementary volume is $dV=(\pi R_2^2-\pi R_1^2)dy=\pi (3^2-(\sqrt y)^2)dy$

Comment: @Beginner You can also refer to http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/VolumeWithRings.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. (+1)

Comment: @Beginner You are welcome! Bye